# Ading and subtracting minimum functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

maybe this is a silly question, but in general does:
$$
\min(a,b) -\min(c,d) + \min(e,f)=\min(a-c+e,b-d+f)
$$
or is there a restriction on the values that $a,b,c,d,e,f$ may take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not hold. Consider the fact that $\min(a,b)=\min(b,a)$.

More concretely, $$\min(2,200)-\min(200,2)+\min(1,1)=1\ne\min(2-200+1,200-2+1)=\min(-197,199)=-197$$

Comment: So is the only way to solve my equation to take different cases about the relationships between the variables?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the only way to explicitly solve your relation above is by plugging in values for $a,b,c,d,e,f$, or at least knowing the relative ordering of the terms, for example (but not necessarily) $a<b<c<d<e<f$.

Comment: what im trying to do is show that for  $a,b,c,d \in 0,1$ and $a<b$, $c<d$: $min(b,d)-min(a,d)-min(b,c)+min(a,c)$ is always non negative, i was looking for a short cut since taking all permutations of their relationships is tedious

Comment: If you know that $a<b$, $c<d$, then you can apply that to your above expression to simplify it considerably.

Comment: but my problem (the one in the comment) requires knowledge of a relationship between $b,d$ $a,d$ $b,c$... doesn't really help to simplify those minimums if i just know that a<b and c<d

Comment: Consider asking a question about your problem, I (or someone else) will be happy to help you this evening.